# Question about failure to match wildcard character "_"

Tags: coq

I am learning coq from the resources available by Software Foundations.
During proving the pigeonhole principle, I tried to define a function to extract from a list a subsequence such that no duplicate elements in it. The following is my definition:

```
Fixpoint norepeat_subseq {X : Type} (l : list X) : list X :=
  match l with
  | [] => []
  | n :: t => match (In n t) with
              | False => n :: norepeat_subseq t
              | _ => norepeat_subseq t 
              end
  end.
```

However, coq returns the message:

```
 Pattern "_" is redundant in this clause.
```

Since it complains that "_" is redundant, I remove it.

```
       | => norepeat_subseq t
```

Now it returns the error message:

Syntax error: [eqn] expected after '|' (in [branches]).

If I removed the whole line of mating condition with the wildcard completely, it passed. So it seems to me that the problem definitely comes from the useage of the wildcard character.
I googled and couldn't find similar questions being asked/answered. Could someone help me out? Thank you very much.

The version of coq I am using is 8.15.2.

Answer (score 1):

When Coq tells you a pattern is redundant, it means that the branch will never be reached so that you should replace `| _ => norepeat_subseq t` with nothing.

The reason why it is redundant is that your other pattern `False` is already a wildcard! Indeed, the `False` type (ie `False : Prop`) is not itself a pattern, so Coq assumes that you are simply matching on a variable called `False` that you are introducing in the branch.

Patterns can only be built from constructors of inductive types or variables. They cannot be types (unless they are variables).
You cannot determine whether a proposition holds simply by pattern matching on it. You need to *decide* the proposition to do this.

In the case of `In` you have the following:

```
List.in_dec:
  ∀ [A : Type],
    (∀ x y : A, {x = y} + {x ≠ y}) → 
    ∀ (a : A) (l : list A), {List.In a l} + {¬ List.In a l}
```

`in_dec dec a l` decides whether `a` belongs to `l` or not, provided you have a way (`dec`) to decide whether two elements of the list are equal or not.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was not aware of such issues. I have to confess that my major is mechanical engineering. So a lot of fundamental concepts in the fields using coq as a basic tool are new to me.  So do you have any hint to reach my goal? All my knowledge comes from Logical Foundations: https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/toc.html ) I just finished "Inductively Defined Propositions". Really thank you for your answer.

Comment: You could replace your match on `In` with a match on `in_dec`. I invite you to use `Print List.in_dec` and stuff like `Search List.In` to find more about these things.

Comment: This should be perceived as a bug in Coq: (In n t) has type Prop, which is not an inductive type, so the error message should be based on this, rather than a "redundant case" rule.

Comment: I think it's not a bug, you can actually write `match Type with x => x end` and it is accepted in Coq. I guess we could argue this is undesirable but I've seen it used.